Questions about the characteristic property of the free vector space
I am self-studying John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifold. I tried to prove the exercise on the book:

Proposition 12.5 (Characteristic Property of the Free Vector Space) 
For any set $S$ and any vector space $W$, every map $A:S\longrightarrow W$ has a unique extension to a linear map $\overline{A}: \mathscr{F}(S) \longrightarrow W$.

Here is my attempt:
Given arbitrary $f\in \mathscr{F}(S)$, we define:
$$
\overline{A}(f) = \overline{A}(\sum_m a^i x_i) = \sum_m a^i \overline{A}(x_i).
$$
Then, we let $\overline{A}(x_i) = A(x_i)$ for all $x_i \in S$.
I believe the above constructed function proves the proposition. It is an extension since we have defined it for all $x_i\in S$ and $S\subseteq \mathscr{F}(S)$. Also, the linearity of the extended function comes from construction. But how do we ensures the uniqueness?
I found an answer to the proof of this proposition Universal Property of free vector space  before posting this. But it would be really appreciated if anyone could answer my question about the uniqueness, and see if my reasoning is consistent.

Your proof of existence is ok (provided you define your notation $f=\sum_m\dots$). Prove the uniqueness with the same formulas: if $\bar A$ is a linear extension of $A$ then $\overline A(\sum_m a^i x_i)=\sum_m a^iA(x_i)$, which determines $\overline A$ uniquely.

One construction of the free vector space on a set is as the vector space with that set as a basis. Thus any linear map out of the free vector space is uniquely determined by what it does on a basis
